# If else error? It says "Syntax error on token else, delete this token, while expected

Tags: java

This is my code. What did I do wrong? sorry I'm just new to this. This is our lab exercise that I couldn't finish.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Conversion {
    public static void main (String []   args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int con;
        double km;
        double mile;

        System.out.println("1 - Kilometer to Mile \n2 - Mile to Kilometer\n\nChoose Convertion:");
        con=input.nextInt();
         if (con==1);
         {
             System.out.println("Enter Kilometer:");
                 km=input.nextDouble();
             System.out .println(km+" kilometers is equivalent to "+ km *0.621371+ " miles.");
         }

         else (con==2);
         {
            System.out.println("Enter Mile:");
                mile=input.nextDouble();
            System.out .println(mile+" miles is equivalent to "+ mile *1.60934+ " kilometers.");
         }


       }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: delete the ; after the if statement

Comment: Remove semicolon after `if (con==1);`

Comment: also the `;` at the else

Answer (score 4):

- Remove semicolon after `if`. No semicolon is needed after `if` or `else if` or `else`.

  ```
  if (con==1);
  __________^^^__
  ```
- Remove semicolon after `else`. Also when you use `else`, you don't need any condition. If you need to check the condition, then use `else if`.

  ```
  else
  ```

  or,

  ```
  else if(con==2)
  ```